# Script behaves differently on other servers

Tags: php, regex

I have a very simple script that seems to behave differently on different servers !

This is the script :

```
<?php
$list = file_get_contents("list.txt");
$list = str_replace(Array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\f"), "\n", $list);
$all = explode("\n\n", $list);


foreach($all as $k  => $v) {

    $b = preg_replace('/\s+/', '^', $v);
    echo $b."<br/><br/>";
     }
?>
```

it reads :

```
System:         Avro
Supplier:       ABC Inc

Quantity:       1
Type:             ICD
Key:              PA-658_ao8uY
For Clarity:  PA-658_AO8UY

Quantity:       10
Type:             PSTHG
Key:              tg675_0O09i8
For Clarity:  PA-658_AO8UY
```

I have 3 servers to test on and I need it to work the same on all 3.
They are php 4.3.10, 5.2.13 & 5.3.5

The script returns this on PHP 5.2.13 - this is what I was expecting.

```
System:^Avro^Supplier:^ABC^Inc

Quantity:^1^Type:^ICD^Key:^PA-658_ao8uY^For^Clarity:^PA-658_AO8UY

Quantity:^10^Type:^PSTHG^Key:^tg675_0O09i8^For^Clarity:^PA-658_AO8UY
```

Yet on 4.3.10 & 5.3.5 I get :

```
System:^ ^ ^ ^ ^Avro^Supplier:^ ^ ^ ^ABC^Inc

Quantity:^ ^ ^ ^1^Type:^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ICD^Key:^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ PA-658_ao8uY^For^Clarity:^ PA-658_AO8UY

Quantity:^ ^ ^ ^10^Type:^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^PSTHG^Key:^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ tg675_0O09i8^For^Clarity:^ PA-658_AO8UY
```

How do I get the output to be the same on all of them ?

Thanks

UPDATE:
I've got this working, by changing :

`$b = preg_replace('/\s+/', '^', $v);`

TO

`$b = preg_replace('/(\s|\xa0)+/', '^', $v);`

Comment: Maybe the problem is with something stated in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php): "Because str_replace() replaces left to right, it might replace a previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements. See also the examples in this document."

Comment: @Voitcus, the `str_replace` portion seems to be working fine.  It is the `preg_replace` that is failing to replace all whitespace.  Could it be a character encoding issue?  Are these systems all the same other than PHP version?

Comment: I don't know, but there are some problems with preg_replace, take a look at [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#85416) and [this one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#84385). Or even with [mb encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this working, by changing :

`$b = preg_replace('/\s+/', '^', $v);`

TO

`$b = preg_replace('/(\s|\xa0)+/', '^', $v);`

Comment: Beware!  This may work for the example text, but it may also corrupt your data by replacing parts of other multi-byte characters.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess: your input data is in a character encoding that allows multi-byte characters, and this is throwing PHP for a loop.

You may need [`mb_ereg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php), the multi-byte version.

For debugging purposes, it may be helpful to look at what actual characters you are receiving, such as using [`ord`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) to look at each byte.

Comment: Thanks. I get `Fatal error: Call to undefined function: mb_ereg_replace() in`  When I try this on my 4.3.10 box..

Comment: @user1635970, according to the docs (linked in my answer) it exists since 4.2.0.

Comment: it appears my 4.3.10 does support with mbstring.
Any other ideas ?

Comment: @user1635970, maybe you need the `--enable-mbstring` option in your configuration?  Here is more information: http://php.undmedlibrary.org/manual/fi/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: dan1111 - thanks for your continued support. I can't change the config on the php4 box, it's pretty much hard coded.

I need to find a way to remove the whitespace that will work for each platform

Comment: @user1635970, it is going to be nearly impossible to handle multibyte character input if you don't have access to those functions.  Is `file.txt` under your control?  If so, you can make sure it is in ASCII.

Comment: Thanks. I've now got this working. I've updated my original post with how.